# how to create js function or hooks to choose the picture clicked as the new item picture in e commerce product page using react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i wrote the following code for product page i am being unable to create a function and confused whether to use hooks or simple scrip

```
import React from 'react'
import Prod from '../assets/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg'
import Cart from '../assets/icon-cart.svg'
import Prod2 from '../assets/image-product-2-thumbnail.jpg'
import Prod3 from '../assets/image-product-3-thumbnail.jpg'
import Prod4 from '../assets/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg'


const Hero = () => {
  return (
<div className='w-full py-[10rem] px-10 bg-white'>
<div className='max-w-[1240px] ml-[300px] grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-10'>
<img className='h-[520px] w-[100] rounded-lg bg-cover ' src={Prod2} alt="/" />
<div className=' flex-col mt-[50px] ml-[60px]' >
<p className='text-orange-500 text-lg text-bold font-bold'>SNEAKER COMPANY</p>
<h1 className=' flex flex-col  text-4xl font-bold' >Fall Limited Edition Sneakers</h1>
<p className=' flex flex-col  text-gray-800' >These low-profile sneakers are your perfect casual wear companion. Featuring a durable rubber outer sole, they’ll withstand everything the weather can offer. </p>
<button className=' ml-4 flex items-center justify-center gap-2 bg-orange-300 hover:bg-orange-500 text-[white] w-[500px] rounded-xl font-large my-6 mx-auto px-10 py-5'><a > <img className='text-white' src={Cart} alt='cart'/> </a>ADD TO CART</button>
</div>   
<div className='max-w-[1240px] ml-0 gap-8 grid grid-cols-4'>
<img className=' rounded-lg bg-cover ' src={Prod} alt="/" />
<img className=' rounded-lg bg-cover ' src={Prod3} alt="/" />
<img className=' rounded-lg bg-cover ' src={Prod4} alt="/" />

</div>

</div>

</div>

);
};

export default Hero;
```

if you would run this snippet you will see a product page with several images of product what i want to do is when a user will click any other photo of the product that photo needs to be shown as the new picture for reference https://yasertarek.github.io/ecommerce-product-page/index.html
Just guide or explain me concept or any link for that for me i want to do this on my own

Comment: You can use `state`. eg: `this.state = {mainPicture: 'pic3.jpg'}` 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of how you can achieve it with `useState()` hook [link to working demo of below code](https://www.loom.com/share/fd198a70e5d04c2a859fefbf46c259c1). Give a default active image source and pass the `src` value of each thumbnail image to the `setActiveImage('src here')` inside `onClick()` which should cause re-render and the active image is replaced by the one you clicked on since it's src value is `activeImage`. I have also attached the styles so you can take a look at it.

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const ModalDemo = () => {
    const [activeImage, setActiveImage] = useState('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1016/3844/2563.jpg?hmac=WEryKFRvTdeae2aUrY-DHscSmZuyYI9jd_-p94stBvc');


    return (
        <div className="slider-container">
            <div className="slider__active-photo">
                <img src={activeImage} alt="active-image" className="active" />
            </div>
            <div className="slider__thumbnails">
                <img onClick={() => setActiveImage('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000.jpg?hmac=yMXsznFliL_Y2E2M-qZEsOZE1micNu8TwgNlHj7kzs8')} src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1014/6016/4000.jpg?hmac=yMXsznFliL_Y2E2M-qZEsOZE1micNu8TwgNlHj7kzs8" alt="" className="thumbnail" />
                <img onClick={() => setActiveImage('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000.jpg?hmac=aHjb0fRa1t14DTIEBcoC12c5rAXOSwnVlaA5ujxPQ0I')} src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1015/6000/4000.jpg?hmac=aHjb0fRa1t14DTIEBcoC12c5rAXOSwnVlaA5ujxPQ0I" alt="" className="thumbnail" />
                <img onClick={() => setActiveImage('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935.jpg?hmac=3N43cQcvTE8NItexePvXvYBrAoGbRssNMpuvuWlwMKg')} src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935.jpg?hmac=3N43cQcvTE8NItexePvXvYBrAoGbRssNMpuvuWlwMKg" alt="" className="thumbnail" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ModalDemo;
```

```css
.slider-container {
    color: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.slider-container img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.slider__thumbnails {
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.slider__thumbnails img {
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you to both of you i owe you for this one <3